# PyTorch Forward Pass with CUDA Tensor and CPU Tensor while Retaining Gradients

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, torch

I have a vector `a` produced by neural model which need to interact with a huge matrix `M`. Since `M` is large, I have to do the computation in cpu device. In this case, I wonder if the gradient can be retained and backwarded on cuda device.

Example as below:

```
a_cuda = torch.randn([1, 512], requires_grad=True).to("cuda")
a_cpu = torch.randn([1, 512], requires_grad=True).to("cpu")

M = torch.randn([512, 100000], requires_grad=False) # loaded in cpu device, dont need update

out_cuda = (a_cuda.cpu() @ M).sum()
out_cuda.backward()

out_cpu = (a_cpu @ M).sum()
out_cpu.backward()

print(a_cuda.grad) # None
print(a_cpu.grad)
```

I am looking for solution such that `a_cuda.grad` has the same gradients as `a_cpu.grad`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

Try this:

```
a_cuda = torch.randn([1, 512], requires_grad=True, device='cuda')
a_cpu = torch.randn([1, 512], requires_grad=True)

M = torch.randn([512, 100000], requires_grad=False) # loaded in cpu device, dont need update

out_cuda = (a_cuda.cpu() @ M).sum()
out_cuda.backward()

out_cpu = (a_cpu @ M).sum()
out_cpu.backward()

print(a_cuda.grad)
print(a_cpu.grad)
```